# Stanford Pattern-based Information Extraction

Tags: stanford-nlp

I really wonder how can I use SPIED (Stanford bootstrapping tool)? Is there any way to have a demo file like what we have for parsers, Ner, .....? The statement in the file is not easy to use... I'm using other tools in my project thanks to demo files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the main method of the class GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass. The static run method inside the class is almost like a demo. All you need is a properties file, an example demo properties file is provided with the release. You can also access the example properties [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/data/edu/stanford/nlp/patterns/surface/example.properties).

You would need to run the class with parameters: " -props [path-to-properties] "

SPIED code is different from NER etc. because there is no model released. The code is generic, like CRFs or logistic regression, which you use to train your own model.

An example code to run SPIED is (you can similarly use :

```html
GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass<SurfacePattern> model = GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.<SurfacePattern>run(props);

for(Map.Entry<String, Counter<SurfacePattern>> p : model.getLearnedPatterns().entrySet()){
  System.out.println("For label " + p.getKey() + ", the patterns learned are: ");
  for(Map.Entry<SurfacePattern, Double> pat: p.getValue().entrySet()){
    System.out.println("Pattern " + pat + " with score " + pat.getValue());
  }
  System.out.println("For label " + p.getKey() + ", the learned words are:  "  + model.constVars.getLearnedWords(p.getKey()));
}
```

For more details on how to use the model for another piece of text, look at explanations of flags loadSavedPatternsWordsDir in the example.properties file.

Comment: @ Sonal Gupta After defining props in my code, I've got an error in "model.constVars" that shows something wrong that might be for "props" definition.                                                                                  Properties props = new Properties();
      InputStream is = null;
      File f = new File("C:\\Applications\\workspace\\RelationExtraction\\Lib\\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20\\input\\example.properties");
      is = new FileInputStream( f );
      props.load(is);

Comment: Can you try this?       Properties props = StringUtils.argsToPropertiesWithResolve(new String[]{"-props","filepath"});

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. See the first problem and solution listed in this document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19m_venIHdA_qfICEQaRbLuyX-JEysm5eTMyIKPTrXmE/edit      Also, which version of CoreNLP are you using and when did you download it?

Comment: Thanks! I got it and both (Win7 and Ubuntu )work well right now. I'm using the very recent version of CoreNlp (04/22/2015). I'm working on the same problem of semantic drift and wonder how could I add and change the code to implement my own approach. I'm able to do it on Basilisk since they provide a  java file but unable to play with your code. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The source code is online. It's in the jar release (see http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/basic-compiling.txt) and it's on Github too (https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP).

Comment: When I want to use FMeasure for scoring patterns, but an error appear saying that its not define in enum. However, I can see Fmeasure in the code as an option of enum.  I observed that you commented a segment related to measuring Fmeasure. Could you tell me how to use Fmeasure?